# Block SSH access from specific countries

Tags: ssh, iptables, port, blocking, country

I found this handy script online, and would like to modify it to only block SSH access but I don't know anything about iptables and Im afraid Ill kill my system as i have no physical access to it.

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_country_block_iptables.php

What should i change to only drop port 22 please?

I ***know*** hackers can use proxies etc and this won't be my only security. This reason for this is only to reduce the number of fail2ban emails i get about automated attacks from China :)

Thanks
Maciej

Answer (score 4):

You need the equivalent to this in your distro:

```
$ apt-cache show xtables-addons-common
Package: xtables-addons-common
Description-en: Extensions targets and matches for iptables [tools, libs]
 Xtables-addons provides extra modules for iptables not present in the
 kernel, and is the successor of patch-o-matic.
 Extensions includes new targets like TEE, TARPIT, CHAOS, or modules like
 geoip and account.
```

You are interested in the `geoip` module.
Then add [some rules](http://people.netfilter.org/acidfu/geoip/howto/) to your `iptables`.

Check the 4th point in the HOWTO.

A simple walkthrough the example rules:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m geoip --src-cc A1,A2 -j DROP
```

The above command adds a rule in the `INPUT` chain that uses the `geoip` module to match connections originating from a specific country, identified by its [ISO 3661](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_txt.htm) code. In this case, [A1 and A2](http://www.shorewall.net/ISO-3661.html) represent:

```
 A1 => "Anonymous Proxy" ,
 A2 => "Satellite Provider" ,
```

This command uses the negation (`!`) to invert the match, resulting in all traffic not originating from the specified country (CA, in this case) being dropped:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc CA -j DROP
```

The last example shows you how create a custom chain in order to analyze traffic to your `sshd` server:

```
# iptables -N SSH_GEOIP
# iptables -A SSH_GEOIP -m geoip --src-cc CA
# iptables -A SSH_GEOIP -m geoip --src-cc DE
# iptables -A SSH_GEOIP -m geoip --src-cc US
# iptables -A SSH_GEOIP -m geoip --src-cc JP
# iptables -A SSH_GEOIP -m geoip --src-cc FR
# iptables -A SSH_GEOIP -m geoip ! --src-cc CA,DE,US,JP,FR
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j SSH_GEOIP
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the binary database and the package installed but don't really understand the commands. What do i really need do drop port 22 from a given country? Also i use UFW for other stuff if that matters.

Comment: Be very careful in my experience it is not very reliable . also puts tremendous amount of workload on firewall. You may need to wait for hours during reboot.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could filter any ssh traffic by using the `hosts.deny` file and then allow traffic from selected countries specifically by querying a shell script in the `hosts.allow` file. See this tutorial: https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/ssh-geoip/

Comment: Please include the basics of the actions needed in your answer, because external link can (and often do) become stale. Furthermore this is more about using 'geoip" than hosts.deny.